# How do you refer to a single corn plant?

Tags: vocabulary

When you want to talk about a single corn plant, do you refer to it at as 'a corn' or 'corn'?

Comment: _Corn plant_ or _stalk_ are the usual ways. Normally you don't pay attention to individual plants of a grain crop.

Comment: In what context would you want to refer to a single corn plant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single corn plant is usually referred to as a ***cornstalk***. This refers to the stem of the plant itself, and would be applicable even if the plant is too young to have actually borne any corn yet. ***Corn*** is typically used as an uncountable noun, referring to large quantity of grain crop. You can't make it singular or plural, since it refers to a mass of objects. If you want to refer to individual members of a field of corn, you'll need to use more specific, countable nouns like corn cob, ear of corn, cornstalk, or corn kernel.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -4):

The correct wording is shown in the sentance ie. *a single corn plant* which is refered to as *a corn*. Corn used individually refers to a number of corn stalks, such as a field of corn. Whereas, "I picked up *a corn*" implies a single piece, but I picked up corn suggests you picked a number of stalks of corn.

Comment: "I picked up a corn" implies that you plucked a lump of skin off your foot.

Comment: Corn is an uncountable noun, like water or air. Referring to "a corn" in this sense isn't grammatically correct. @HotLicks is correct, the kinds of corns that are countable include foot callouses and peppercorns, but not cornstalk corn, so if you talk about "a corn", you're not referring to the yellow food.